# Accessing member of parent class "Invalid use of non-static data member" C++

Tags: c++, xcode

I am trying to implement a child class that inherits the constructor from a parent class and subsequently access a member of the parent class which is initialized in that constructor.

So, I will have something like this:

parent.h:

```
#include "myClass.h"

class parent
{

public:

    myClass foo;

    virtual void myFunc();

    parent(int a);

};
```

parent.cpp:

```
#include "parent.h"

parent::parent(int a)
{

    foo = myClass(a);

}

 void parent::myFunc()
{
 (do stuff)
}
```

child.h:

```
#include "parent.h"

class child: public parent
{

public:

    using parent::parent;
    void myFunc();

};
```

child.cpp:

```
#include "child.h"

void myFunc()
{
    myClass tmp = foo;
}
```

The issue is that when I try to access the instance of myClass (foo) in child.cpp, I am getting the error "Invalid use of non-static data member 'foo'". Oddly, I can access foo from the main program (child.foo causes no issues in main).

I am very new to c++ so I apologize in advance if this is a poor description of my problem. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: `void myFunc()` is not a member of `child`, but a regular, non-member, standalone function that just happens to have the same name. Curiously, you know enough to have defined `parent::myFunc` correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void myFunc()
{
    myClass tmp = foo;
}
```

defines a global function, not a member function. Add the class scope to make it a member function.

```
void child::myFunc()
{
    myClass tmp = foo;
}
```